# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx

Hi all i am getting a unique key prop warning
here is my code

```
 const catFilter=(categoryListCountAbove30: any[], InOrOut:any)=>{
        console.log('1stloaded')
        return categoryListCountAbove30.map((category) => (
             <>
                {categoryFilterId == category.id ?
                    (
                        <SelectCategoryBtn key={category.id}>
                            {category.categoryName}
                        </SelectCategoryBtn>
                    ) :
                    (
                        <CategoryBtn key={category.id} onClick={() => {
                            setCategoryFilterId(category.id)
                            setCategoryFilterName(category.categoryName)
                            {InOrOut=="inner"?(
                                setManufactureFilterId(""),
                            setManufactureFilterName(""),
                            setManufactureModelTypeId(""),
                            setManufactureModelTypeName(""),
                            // setFilterLetter("")
                            setGetToHome("Manufacturer")
                            ):[]}
                            console.log(category.id)
                        }}>
                            {category.categoryName}
                        </CategoryBtn>
                        
                    )}   
            </>

        ))
    }
```

i was tried some code but it doesn't working please help to solve this warning.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The key should be on the root element, in this case its the React.Fragment, therefore:

```
const catFilter = (categoryListCountAbove30: any[], InOrOut: any) => {
  return categoryListCountAbove30.map((category) => {
    return <React.Fragment key={category.id}>...</React.Fragment>;
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but still i am getting same warning

Comment: So the warning does not coming from this code, please just share a reproducible example in codesandbox for example

Comment: ok dannis vash, and for me when reload the page this warning occurs